# How to get Twitter User Email using Xamarin.Auth library

Tags: email, twitter, xamarin, oauth, twitter-oauth

I m trying to implement twitter authentication for my xamarin app. I checked Request email addresses from users option on developer console but i am not able to get email in user information. Am i doing something wrong

```
var Twitterauth = new OAuth1Authenticator(

consumerKey: "XXXX",
consumerSecret: "XXX",
requestTokenUrl:new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
authorizeUrl:    new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
accessTokenUrl:  new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
callbackUrl:     new Uri("http://www.isportfoy.com.tr/tr/anasayfa") 

);

Twitterauth.Completed += (s, ee) =>

{
   if (ee.IsAuthenticated)
        {

           var request = new OAuth1Request(
                        "GET",
                         new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"),
                        null,
                        ee.Account);

                    request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        var res = t.Result;
                        var resString = res.GetResponseText();
                        Console.WriteLine("Result Text: " + resString);
                    });
}
                else 
                {

                }

            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter API requires us to indicate if we want to the user email in the response.

Based on the Twitter Documentation this can be done sending the `include_email` as true.

Full documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials

Comment: thank you. Apparently you have to add  them as parameter...   as fallows.        
    Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    param.Add("include_email","true");                                                                                                         var request = new OAuth1Request("GET", newUri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"),
 param,
 ee.Account);
 request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
 {
  var res = t.Result;
  var resString = res.GetResponseText(); 
   });

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but yeah that's indeed what I meant. You need to send this field as a parameter of the request.

Comment: Thanks apineda and @BahadirGul  for detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    param.Add("include_email","true");
    var request = new OAuth1Request(
        "GET",
        new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"),
        param,
        e.Account);
}
```